# Show that the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]n-1\right)$ is divergent.

Tags: real-analysis

$x_{n} = \sqrt[n]{n} - 1$

$n= \left(1 + x_{n}\right)^{\,n}$ which means $\ln\left(n\right) = n\ln\left(1 + x_{n}\right)$

This is about as far as I can go. I have no idea how to continue solving it or if ieven wrote it correctly the first time.

Comment: Please take the time to type your math using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  It helps create a clearer more readable format for everyone.  I did my best to try and fix it up, but if anything seems off, please fix it.

Comment: Good to put parentheses in the series.

Answer (score 1):

$$x_n=n^{\frac {1}{n}}-1$$

$$=e^{{\frac 1n}\ln (n)}-1$$

now use the equivalence

$$e^X-1\sim X \;\;(X\to 0) $$

to get

$$x_n\sim \frac {1}{n}\ln (n)=y_n$$

but

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} ny_n=+\infty $$

thus for great enough $n $,

$$ny_n>1$$ or $$\frac {1}{n}<y_n $$
which means that the series $\sum y_n $ and $\sum x_n $ are divergent.

Comment: e^X−1∼X(X→0)- how did you get the right side of this? I understand where you received the left side from.

Comment: from the well-known limit $\lim_0 (\frac {e^x-1}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the function $\displaystyle\;\frac{\log x}{x}$ is monotonic decreasing for $x \ge e$. 
This means for any $k \ge 3$, we have

$$\sqrt[k]{k} - 1 = e^{\frac{\log k}{k}} - 1 \ge \frac{\log k}{k} \ge \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{\log x}{x} dx$$
As a result, when $n \ge 3$, we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sqrt[k]{k} - 1\right) \ge \left(\sqrt{2}-1\right) + \int_3^{n+1}\frac{\log x}{x} dx
= \frac{(\log(n+1))^2}{2} + \left(\sqrt{2}-1 -\frac{(\log 3)^2}{2}\right)$$

and the partial sums diverges as least as fast as $\displaystyle\;\frac{(\log(n))^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

From where you left off: $x_n \ge \ln(1+x_n) = \dfrac{\ln n}{n}\implies \displaystyle \sum x_n \ge \displaystyle \sum \dfrac{\ln n}{n} > \displaystyle \sum \dfrac{1}{n} = \infty\implies \displaystyle \sum x_n = +\infty$. I realized that my answer is almost the same as the first answer and probably ended up accidentally using the second answer's idea in certain way, but it seems to be very easy to follow hence I post it.